# Base Controller Get Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I having trouble getting a value to my base controller. All I would like to do is have my base controller pick up an ID from an ActionLink?

**Link**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { SectionId = 1 })%>
```

**Base Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class SectionController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Section/

        public SectionController(int SectionId)
        {
            if (SectionId == 1)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "GOT AN ID";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "NO ID";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Home Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : SectionController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }

   }
}
```

**Solution so far**

**ActionLink**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", new { SectionId = 1})%>
```

**SectionAttribute.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Website.ActionFilters
{
    public class SectionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
        // Actions have sectionId parameter
        object SectionId = filterContext.ActionParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "SectionId").Value;

            if (SectionId != null && (int)SectionId == 1)
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "GOT AN ID";
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "NO ID";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SectionController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.ActionFilters;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    [Section]
    public class SectionController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work. Instead you should define `OnActionExecuting` method in base controller, where you get actual sectionId from route data and set ViewData accordingly. Try something like this (not tested):

```
public class SectionController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Actions have no sectionId parameter - look for it in querystring
        string SectionId = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["sectionId"];

        int sId;

        if (int.TryParse(SectionId, out sId) && sID == 1)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "GOT AN ID";
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "NO ID";
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

You can move this out from controller and create ActionFilter. It is very simple:

```
public class SectionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Actions have sectionId parameter
        object SectionId = filterContext.ActionParameters
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "sectionId").Value;

        if (SectionId != null && (int)SectionID == 1)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "GOT AN ID";
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Message"] = "NO ID";
        }
    }
}

...

[Section]
public class SectionController : Controller {

or

[HandleError, Section]
public class HomeController : SectionController {
```

Comment: +1 Still better is we can move this out from the base class and put it in an action-filter/attribute to make it more elegant ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying the code but I'm getting the error below on the OnActionExecuting.

Error 2 'Website.Controllers.SectionController.OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)'

Comment: OnActionExecuted has protected modifier in controllers and public - in filters - I've fixed my answer

Comment: I've not created an ActionFilter before so bare with me. Where should I save an ActionFilter class to? Also if my base controller inherits the section ActionFilter will that be available to all my views?

Comment: Just create separate file SectionAttribute.cs and put the code there; Dont forget to add using Namespace.Of.SectionAttribute to your controllers; You can decorate base controller with this attribute and it will work for all inherited controllers

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm nearly there just getting one error on the SectionAttribute.cs file.

Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'.

I'll update my original question with the solution I've git so far.

Comment: Why does SectionId need to be an object rather than a Var?

I'm getting no errors but when I click my ActionLink I'm only getting "NO ID" on each page. So it's like its not picking up the ID?

Comment: You have to add SectionId parameter to each Action or change `object SectionId = filterContext.RouteData.Values["sectionId"];` to `string SectionId = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["sectionId"];`

Comment: Thanks for the update but now I'm getting the error below on the updated code...

The given key was not present in the dictionary.

// Actions have SectionId parameter
object SectionId = filterContext.ActionParameters["SectionId"];

Comment: No errors now but I'm still not picking up the ID as my views still say "NO ID"

Answer (score 0):

A constructor of a base controller is not typically the place where common code is placed. You usually create a filter for common code. If you decorate the base controller with this filter attribute, then all inheriting controllers use that filter.

Comment: I'm new to .net and mvc. How would I go about creating a filter?